# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ converge: prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^2}$ converge absolutely.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need help proving the following:

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)$ converges:

prove $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^2}$$ converges absolutely.

I managed to prove that the series converge using Abel's test but I can't find a way to show it's converging absolutely.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges, the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown how that helps proving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Lord Shark comment,If $\sum{a_{n}}$ converges then the sequence $a_{n}$ is a bounded sequence which means that there exists $M$ such that $|a_{n}| \leq M \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$,so for dealing with the absolute convergence we take the absolute value of the sequential terms as

$\sum{|\frac{a_{n}}{n^2}|} \leq \sum {\frac{M}{n^2}}$ , now we know that the right side sum converges and by comparision test we can say that the absolute convergence is obtained!

Comment: You are welcome! all the best :)